# spring destroy bean manually instead of ctx.close()

Tags: spring, javabeans, destroy

is it possible to tell the container of spring to destroy a specific bean (prototype) in order to save up memory?

I dont want to user ctx.close() in order to see this bean destroyed, but rather on runtime.

Comment: do use annotations or xml configuration for beans ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to remove bean that was defined in the ctx at runtime, will I use `BeanDefinitionRegistry` to get this done, `BeanDefinitionRegistry` has a method of removeBean() which takes the bean name as the parameter.

```
BeanDefinitionRegistry factory = 
   (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationCtx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
```

Then

```
((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).destroySingleton("myBean");
```

**EDIT**

reference http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html#removeBeanDefinition%28java.lang.String%29