# Spring destroy bean runtime

Tags: spring

My bean has a @PreDestroy annotated method which do some clean up. I want to destroy this bean at run time (in response to some ApplicationEvent) such that its preDestroy method is called.

Can any one please guide me?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373276/predestroy-method-of-a-spring-singleton-bean-not-called

Comment: Here's a [similar questions with an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667957/spring-destroy-bean-manually-instead-of-ctx-close).